# Optimising CSS: Sprite or repeating background image?

Tags: html, css, performance, css-sprites

So my task is to optimise the CSS for a Website. Currently, their buttons are all done using image sprites like the following:

[image: Image button sprite]

These sprites are all put into one large .png (40 or so different buttons on it).

If I were to do the buttons as HTML instead of images, I imagine it would be something like the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
  a.button
  {
    display: block;
    width: 175px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url("../images/green-gradient.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }

  a.button:hover
  {
   background: url("../images/green-gradient-hover");
  }
</style>

<a href="#" class="button">Arrange Demo</a>
```

Would it be more optimal to do these buttons as HTML as detailed above (with repeating a repeating background image that is 1px by 35px), or sprites like they are currently?

If I did do it as HTML like above, are there any performance implications of using a different repeated background on hover?

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?  You can use CSS3 gradients if you don't have to support any of the ancient browsers.

Comment: The method outlined above would be better than a large sprite as obviously loading a small 1px wide graphic would be quicker. You could also consider using pure CSS via CSS3 gradients. Have a look at how Bootstrap makes its buttons for aome top tips: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Comment: I need browser support up to when the Egyptians were building the pyramids. Are CSS3 gradients the most efficient then? I don't know if I can be bothered to set it up to revert to using images for older browsers

Comment: They are the most efficient as they are pure code, it allows the browser to render the gradient itself rather than having to read a JPG image (or whatever format image for that matter)

Comment: You could also have both the hover and the normal state bg in the same sprite. I would go with CSS3 if you can get away with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're method above would definitely be more efficient as you are loading a smaller file and re-using it.  That said, it could be more efficient by using CSS3 gradients if possible.  You can also use some javascript to make it more browser friendly, like modernizr.

See [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights#) to analyze your sites loads times.

See [Can I Use It](http://caniuse.com/css-gradients) to see browser support for CSS3 gradients.